# Film Featuring a Piano or a Harpsicord

Tags: story-identification, movie

There's a film with a bizarre ending.

A man stands on a hill. The atmosphere is surreal. A woman talks to him.

He runs down the hill to houses that feel haunted.

He enters a house.

He finds a woman at a piano or harpsicord. A ray of light ensconces the woman. When the man touches the light, it hurts him.

There's a child in the room, too. He's ensconced by light.

The woman from the hill speaks to him. She seems responsible for the situation in the room. We'll call her "the adversary" here for future references.

The man musters up courage and strength, breaking through the "light" to save the woman at the piano or the harpsicord. They both rush to the child, breaking him free from his prison of light.

As the man succeeds in rescuing woman and child, the piano or harpsicord seems to attack "the adversary" with "light." "The adversary" cries out and seems to evaporate into thin air.

I always felt the scene was a metaphor for the power of love versus "evil."

I remember the scenes being black and white. I remember also that the film has color after "the adversary" vanishes. This suggests that the use of "black and white" scenes was a creative decision intended to convey feelings of forlornness. The return to color in later scenes suggests a return to normalcy and hope.

This film was on cable in the late 80s to early 90s.

Comment: Was this film in English? Did it seem like that was the original language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like the final scenes of *[Invitation to Hell](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087480/)*. The [whole movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fssQqdTALnA) is on YouTube and the scenes that you remember start at [1:24:14](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fssQqdTALnA&t=5054s).

Most of the details are a close match to what you remember:

- A scene of the outside of the houses where the woman was trapped.
- The woman playing the piano.
- The woman being trapped in a ray of light.
- A child also trapped in a ray of light.
- The man breaking through the light to rescue the woman and child.
- The piano attacking the adversary with light - it actually launched its keys, and they didn't hit the adversary directly.

The only detail that doesn't match is the scene being in black and white. Although the scene of the outside of the houses does have some strange colour effects, and the lighting of the scenes of the woman playing the piano is quite harsh.